# Grandpa and numbers: Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Grandpa loves to  make silly little statements. And he thinks they are riddles.

The other day he turned to me and said:

> "This is not math but
>
> Take a number
>
> Add a number to it
>
> And you are finished"

What is he talking about?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a number

> D (500 in Roman numerals)

Add a number to it

> one

And you are finished

> done

Comment: Great.Too Fast @jafe. Here is one for you. Take a number  add a number and you become an animal

Comment: I have never heard of that number before... turns out Rot13(Y vf nyfb n ahzore; Y = 50) after doing a little bit of research. $(+1)$ :P

Comment: Cv + T = cvt? (T orvat Pngnyna'f pbafgnag, nccebkvzngryl 0.916)

Comment: It was a trick question. C + AT = CAT   Get it?

Comment: Haha, I see. A...T... wouldn't have guessed that one :D

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer:

> Adding 10 (X in Roman numerals) to Euler's number (e) means that you are finished with your Significant Other. (You are now an "ex").

Alternative alternative answer: (Aiming for the world record in the category of "the largest finite number used in a gratuitous wordplay")

> Grandpa has confused addition with [hexation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation). (Happens to the best of us from time to time).
>
>  Choosing a 3 as both of the numbers, we get $3 \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3$ (in [Knuth's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)), which can also be written as [$g_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number), or "g-one".
>
>  Both "You are finished!" and "You are gone!" are serious threats on the health and life of the other person.

Comment: You should meet my Grandpa @Bass!!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is

> "DONE"

since

> D is a number in Roman. Add one and you are done

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! Great answer... but unfortunately, [@jafe's answer above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70518/grandpa-and-numbers-another-grandpa-mystery/70519#70519) has the exact same idea. Also, whenever you answer, ensure to hide the answer in a spoiler tag/quote `>!` in order to not spoil the answer for other users attempting to solve the puzzle! Consequently, I have proposed such an edit. And, since you are new, I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Comment: Happy Puzzling! :D